# How can I make it so that both player move when they are touches?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making this game where your supposed to play dodgeball against another person. The problem is that I don't get paddlei to move when I touch it. When I touch paddle it moves but it also moves paddlei. What can I do or change?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)


    let touchi = touches.first
    let touchLocationi = touchi!.locationInNode(self)
    if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation) {
        if body.node!.name == PaddleCategoryName {
            print("Began touch on paddle")
            isFingerOnPaddle = true
        }
    }
    if let otherBody = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocationi) {
        if otherBody.node!.name == PaddleyName {
            print("EL otro toco")
            isFingerOnPaddlei = true
        }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    isFingerOnPaddle = false
    isFingerOnPaddlei = false
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if isFingerOnPaddle {
        // 2
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
        let previousLocation = touch!.previousLocationInNode(self)
        // 3
        let paddle = childNodeWithName(PaddleCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
        // 4
        var paddleY = paddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y)
         var paddleX = paddle.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)
        // 5
        paddleY = max(paddleY, paddle.size.width/2)
        paddleY = min(paddleY, size.height - paddle.size.height/2)
        paddleX = max(paddleX, paddle.size.height/2)
        paddleX = min(paddleX, size.height - paddle.size.width/2)
        // 6
        paddle.position = CGPoint(x: paddleX, y: paddleY)

        if isFingerOnPaddlei {

        let paddlei = childNodeWithName(PaddleyName) as! SKSpriteNode


        // 4
        var paddleS = paddlei.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y)
        var paddleU = paddlei.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)
        // 5
        paddleS = max(paddleS, paddlei.size.width / 2)
        paddleS = min(paddleS, size.height - paddlei.size.height / 2)
        paddleU = max(paddleU, paddlei.size.height / 2)
        paddleU = min(paddleU, size.height - paddlei.size.width / 2)
        // 6
        paddlei.position = CGPoint(x: paddleU, y: paddleS)

        }




    }


}
```

}

Comment: Try moving `if isFingerOnPaddlei {..}` outside of the other if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

`if isFingerOnPaddle` is within the if statement stating `if isFingerOnPaddle`. The second if statement will never be called because it is nested, and the two should never be true at the same time.